# Javascript parentNode and innerHTML do not work properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, innerhtml

I have a problem when using javascript in Firefox,  here is the html:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>  
        <TABLE align="center">  
            <TR><td><input type=button name=submit onclick="javascript:submitIt()" value="submit" align="center"></td></TR>
            <TD>
                    <TABLE>     
                            <DIV STYLE="display:none position:relative;">   
                                <FORM ID="formA" NAME="formA" METHOD="post" ACTION="b.html" TARGET="_blank">
                                <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME=aInput VALUE="1294457296">        
                                </FORM>
                            </DIV>
                </TABLE>
            </TD>
        </TABLE></BODY></HTML>
```

and here's the javascript:

```
    <script language="Javascript">
    function submitIt()
{
    oForm = document.getElementById("formA");
    strRequest = "<HTML><BODY>" + oForm.parentNode.innerHTML + "</BODY></HTML>";
    newDoc = window.open("", "", "");
    newDoc.document.write(strRequest);  
}
```

Problem is when you click submit button in this html page, you'll get a new html with source:

```
<HTML><BODY><form id="formA" name="formA" method="post" action="b.html" target="_blank"></form>
                                <input name="aInput" value="1294457296" type="hidden">  </BODY></HTML>
```

but it's supposed to be

```
<HTML><BODY><form id="formA" name="formA" method="post" action="b.html" target="_blank">
                                <input name="aInput" value="1294457296" type="hidden"></form>   </BODY></HTML>
```

Could anyone please help please? it will be really appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: @user649420 I would start by validating your HTML. I see errors in the HTML you're starting with. Also, use a `DOCTYPE` - it's important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your HTML is seriously broken, so the DOM you end up with isn't as expected due to error handling - [install Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and have a look at the resulting DOM.

Wrapping the `<form>` in the missing `<tr><td>...</td></tr>` should give you more like the expected DOM.

Your outer `<table>` is also missing a `<tr>` around the second `<td>`.

Comment: Thanks very much insin, looks like wrapping the <form> with <td><td>, can fix this issue, so I assume every <form> should be wrapped by <td>

Comment: Thanks again insin! The problem solved, I asked this question because I found this html code works good with IE8 and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

parentNode and innerHTML works properly in firefox, your problem comes from your html code which is not valid.